# Removing files from githubs repository but not locally

Tags: git, gradle, github, gitignore

So this is my repository: https://github.com/quinnliu/WalnutiQ

I added .gradle & build/ to my .gitignore file. However when I push this change I would like to remove the .gradle file and build/ folder from ONLY my repository and not locally. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `git rm --cached` to remove the files from the index, but not from your working tree. Commit, then push.

Note that they will still live on in your commit history. Removing them from history entirely is another, more complicated matter.

---

```
$ git clone https://github.com/quinnliu/WalnutiQ.git
$ cd WalnutiQ
$ git rm -r --cached build .gradle
$ ls -a
...
build
...
.gradle
...
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       deleted:    .gradle/1.10/taskArtifacts/cache.properties
#       deleted:    .gradle/1.10/taskArtifacts/cache.properties.lock
#       deleted:    .gradle/1.10/taskArtifacts/fileHashes.bin
#       deleted:    .gradle/1.10/taskArtifacts/fileSnapshots.bin
#       deleted:    .gradle/1.10/taskArtifacts/outputFileStates.bin
#       deleted:    .gradle/1.10/taskArtifacts/taskArtifacts.bin
#       deleted:    build/libs/WalnutiQ.jar
#       deleted:    build/tmp/jar/MANIFEST.MF
#
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, I just tried this and it did not work. Would you mind looking at my .gitignore file in my repo and letting me know if I did something wrong?

Comment: Define "did not work". I also just tried it and it worked fine (see edit).

Comment: My bad I forgot to include the . infront of gradle. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After add `.gradle` on `.gitignore`, I just use

```
git rm -r .gradle
```

to clean my repository.

I can sync gradle again on Android Studio, it will create new `.gradle` on local without getting push on git.